# Agregar url dinamica en filesystem.php

Tags: laravel

estoy instalando un file-manager de unisharp en laravel y en una configuración pide que se coloque el APP_URL y en filesystem.php tengo la siguiente configuración

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

el problema es que estoy usando tenancyforlaravel por lo cual necesito que en 'url' no colocar el env('APP_URL') sino que cargue dinámicamente la url, alguien sabría como hacerlo?

Comment: No creo que se pueda hacer en el archivo de config porque esos archivos son cargados antes que el AppServiceProvider. Cuándo y cómo obtienes la url que quieres ponerle al disco?

Comment: Podrías hacer algo [así](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369819/add-laravel-storage-disk-filesystem-on-the-fly), de una manera que puedas hacer `Storage::disk($tenant)->url($filename)`

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar dejando APP_URL en blanco! que por alguna razón, no es lo mismo dejar APP_URL en blanco en el .env  que eliminando env('APP_URL') en el url del filesystem.